# Merging a date column and a time column to a new column

Tags: date, csv, f#, f#-data

I have a CSV file. There is a column which contains dates and a column with time values:

```
"Datum";"Von";"bis";"Vertikale Netzlast [MW]";
01.01.2015;00:00;00:15;1.216;
01.01.2015;00:15;00:30;1.121;
01.01.2015;00:30;00:45;1.090;
01.01.2015;00:45;01:00;981;
01.01.2015;01:00;01:15;829;
01.01.2015;01:15;01:30;745;
01.01.2015;01:30;01:45;596;
01.01.2015;01:45;02:00;521;
01.01.2015;02:00;02:15;440;
...
02.01.2015;00:00;00:15;-2.990;
02.01.2015;00:15;00:30;-3.114;
02.01.2015;00:30;00:45;-3.319;
02.01.2015;00:45;01:00;-3.389;
02.01.2015;01:00;01:15;-3.479;
02.01.2015;01:15;01:30;-3.649;
02.01.2015;01:30;01:45;-3.778;
02.01.2015;01:45;02:00;-3.873;
02.01.2015;02:00;02:15;-3.821;
02.01.2015;02:15;02:30;-3.831;
```

How can I get a new column by merging "Datum" and "Von" to:

```
01.01.2015 00:00;
01.01.2015 00:15;
01.01.2015 00:30;
01.01.2015 00:45;
01.01.2015 01:00;
01.01.2015 01:15;
01.01.2015 01:30;
01.01.2015 01:45;
...
```

**EDIT:**

I tried this function to do that:

```
let newData = 
    [ for row in data.Rows do
        yield row.Datum.Add(row.Von.TimeOfDay) row.MW
]
```

But then I get this error message for `yield row.Datum.Add(row.Von.TimeOfDay)`:

This is not a function and cannot be applied.

Comment: You should consider posting what you have tried to do....

Comment: @Ringil I edited my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I missed a comma:

```
let newData = 
    [ for row in data.Rows do
        yield row.Datum.Add(row.Von.TimeOfDay), row.MW
]
```

Comment: @Foggy Because it's my own answer and I mark it as solved only after two days ;)

Comment: =) although it is weird to me

Comment: @FoggyFinder Sorry, I meant it is not possible to mark your own answer as solved within two days. :P